# Wifi adapter not working Kali linux

Tags: linux, networking, debian, kali-linux, wifi-driver

I have searched alot and everywhere the issues are with the kali os ran through virtual machines. I have installed Kali linux latest version 2016.1 on my laptop. And its the single os on my laptop, still the wifi is not showing. I have checked ifconfig it shows only loopback and ethernet adapter and on iwconfig it says there are no such adapter. But my laptop has wirekess adapters. I am looking for the solution please help!
I checked compat wireless, it only shows wlan0 but doesn't work.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution. We just have to upgrade our distro and kali now has provided the fix.

apt-get -yf install dist-upgrade
now this will take some time  and your problem will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Nearly all of hp laptops have this issue , it's the wifi adapter which only has one antenna and so you need to install a different firmware. I have to do it again and again so I made a script. Plug an Ethernet connection using USB tethering and

make a file fixwifi.sh using

```
nano fixwifi.sh
```

Copy the contents

```
apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r) git build-essential dkms
git clone git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de
echo "options rtl8723de ant_sel=2" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf
```

Save the file with

```
Ctrl+s and Ctrl+x
```

Execute it using

```
chmod +x fixwifi.sh && ./fixwifi.sh
```

and you are good to go.

Comment: The master branch of this repo is officially abandoned. If you are running a kernel newer than 5.0, use the drivers built into your kernel. That is a lot less work. git checkout origin/rtw88 -b rtw88

Answer (score 0):

> on iwconfig it says there are no such adapter.

It seems that the driver of your wireless adapter isn't loaded. Please look for the driver of your wireless adaptor on the official website of the manufacturer.

The kali Linux is based on Debian. So you may try to install the drivers for Debian. If it doesn't work, you may need to find the source code and compile & install it manually.

Comment: How to install those drivers? I tried but the problem wasn't solved.

Comment: @Chirag The manufacture should provide the guide about how to compile and install it manually. If there is a binary package, just install it and load the module. Here is a good guide: https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi